# C++ writing a string to a line in a text file; New line issue \n not working

Tags: c++, database, file, ifstream

I am writing a database program with many features (Read, write, delete, search, login ect. ) and my writing feature just stopped working (It was working 3 days ago) and I have no idea what changed. My writing function (void savescore) is supposed to write my input (cin username and password) and then move to the next line so I can input some more info the next time I decide to go and write to the file. Right now it's just writing over what I last put in.

test2.txt -
Username, Password

Then I go to edit and enter "User, Pass" and this is what happens

test2.txt - User, Pass

I want it to enter that on the next line and I did "\n" Can someone give me some help? Thanks

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

// Variables
string username;
string password;

//alphabet order functions

// Functions
void SaveScore()
{
  ofstream Database;
Database.open("test2.txt");
Database << username << " " << password << "\n";


Database.seekp(0,std::ios::end); //to ensure the put pointer is at the end
Database.close();
}

int main()
{

    int db;

    char ans;

    string save;

    string file;

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    string searchpar;

    char repeat;
    bool loop = true;
    while (loop == true)
    {

        cout << "WELCOME TO MY DATABASE\n\n";
        cout << "To view the database, press 1\nTo edit the database, press 2\nTo search the database, press 3\nTo log in, press 4\n";
        cin >> db;
        system("CLS");

        if (db == 1)
        {
            cout << "Here is the database: \n\n";

            string line;

            ifstream myfile("test2.txt");
            if (myfile.is_open())
            {
                while (getline(myfile, line))
                {
                    cout << line << '\n';

                }

            }

            //open while bracket
            cout << "\n\nWould you like to return to the menu(y/n)?";
            cin >> repeat;

            if (repeat == 'y')
            {
                loop = true;
            }

            else if (repeat == 'n')
            {
                loop = false;
            }
            system("CLS");

        }

        else if (db == 2)
        {

            cout << "Please enter your username : ";
            cin >> username;

            cout << "\nPlease enter your password: ";
            cin >> password;

            SaveScore();

            cout << "\n\nWould you like to return to the menu(y/n)?";
            cin >> repeat;

            if (repeat == 'y')
            {
                loop = true;
            }

            else if (repeat == 'n')
            {
                loop = false;
            }
            system("CLS");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Database.close();` Remove this, it's too early.

Comment: Also unnecessary. `ofstream` [is implemented with RAII in mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), and will close for you on destruction.

Comment: How do you expect to `Database.seekp()` after `Database.close()`? What do you think `Database.close()` does?

Comment: Recommendation: Keep multiple versions of your code. Use a version control system if you fee like it. That way when something suddenly stops working, you can compare against the previous version and see what you changed.

Comment: "no idea what changed" - Use source control! Then you can go back and see what changed, or check out a previously working version.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, unfortunatly, It's still just replacing the first line of the text file everytime I try to write something new into it. I have the \n in my savescore function so I'm really confused.

Comment: Strip this down a little at a time, until either the error suddenly vanished -- in which case the thing you just removed was causing it -- or you get a very simple program that writes two hard-coded lines to a file (unsuccessfully). This is what we call a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the ability to make one is a vital programming skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say your program is

> replacing the first line of the text file everytime I try to write something new into it

As it turns out, that's exactly what you have asked it to do. Consider:

```
Database << username << " " << password << "\n";
Database.seekp(0,std::ios::end); //to ensure the put pointer is at the end
```

You are opening the file (when the write pointer starts at the start of the file, writing some data, and then seeking to the end. Seeking to the end does not change the fact that you've already written the text. Swap the order of the above lines to get what you want.

Alternatively, you can open the file in "append" mode using:

```
Database.open("test2.txt", std::ios::app);
```

In this situation, you can omit the call to `seekp` entirely, since all data will automatically be written to the end of the file. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream for full documentation on this.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up using the Database.open("test2.txt", std::ios::app); and it worked! Thanks again everyone for your help.